# Program to calculate first two factors (except 1) of given number in python

Tags: python, factors

The question is as follows:
Student is in python lab. She stuck in between to calculate first two factors (other than 1) of a given positive integer. Write a program to calculate first two factors of given number and let student know in case number is not having any factor.
I am trying like this:

```
def factor(num):
    for x in range(1, num+1):
        if num%x==0:
            if x!=1:
                print(x)

num = int(input())
factor(num)
```

but this way, it is printing all the factors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you would not need to check if x=1 if you start the `range` from 2.

If the input is going to be a large number, you can use a counter to make sure you do not run the loop to find all the factors:

```
def factor(num):
    counter = 0
    for i in range(2, num):
        if counter == 2:
            break
        if num%i == 0:
            counter += 1
            print(i)
```

Otherwise, a list comprehension would be much more efficient:

```
[i for i in range(2, num+1) if inp%i==0][:2]
```

Comment: Thanks and how to let student know that in case number is not having any factor.